# How to fix a broken package, when "apt-get install -f" does not work?

Tags: apt

I tried to install [Scala with the typesafe stack](http://typesafe.com/technology/scala) and got into trouble. Now I cannot do much with apt (except update), the broken package seems to be impossible to remove/clean:

Here's the result of `apt-get -f install`:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gstreamer0.10-fluendo-mp3:i386 scala-library liboil0.3:i386
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  scala
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  scala
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 21.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Get:1 http://apt.typesafe.com/ unicorn/main scala all 2.9.2-400 [21.5 MB]
Fetched 21.5 MB in 13s (1,567 kB/s)                                                                          
(Reading database ... 329381 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking scala (from .../scala_2.9.2-400_all.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/scala_2.9.2-400_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/java/scala-partest.jar', which is also in package scala-library 2.9.1.dfsg-3
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/scala_2.9.2-400_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Here's my attempt to `autoremove`:

```
$ apt-get autoremove
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
phdp@desktop:~/work/manuscripts/ideas/ibm_food_webs$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 typesafe-stack : Depends: scala but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Answer (score 64):

I fixed my issue using this command:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite path-to-the-deb-file
```

If `--force-overwrite` doesn't work, try:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite-all path-to-the-deb-file
```

In your case:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/scala_2.9.2-400_all.deb
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You just made my day. This helped me where 'sudo apt --fix-broken install' failed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Mine too. Unmet dependencies with cuda-drivers!

Comment: Helped with this mongodb issue: dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-database-tools-extra_5.0.6_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/install_compass', which is also in package mongodb-org-tools 4.2.0
 Thanks alot

Answer (score 29):

the following command worked.

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/updates/*
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/*.bin
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

if still getting same error then try

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq package_name
```

after removing package update your system and restart once.

Comment: Remarkable how anyone could ever have come up with that exact sequence of commands.

Comment: I have installed wrong version of GitLab CE 13.7 package (deb for the other Debian version) and only `dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq package_name` has helped me to fix it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: take my f***in upvote!!!

Answer (score 13):

It seems like removing the `scala-library` package and then reconfiguring might work. So you're on the right track. The correct commands are, in this order:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Your `autoremove` command did not succeed because you did not run it as `root` (using `sudo`).

Comment: Actually, he reran the autoremove after it told him he was not root. Look at the third line.

Comment: doesn't work...

Comment: I found this set of commands useful as it identified the culprit who caused the bad dependency, allowing me to remove it normally.  Otherwise it was a mystery who was causing the issue.

Answer (score 9):

In my case this worked:

```
sudo dpkg -P package_name
```

(not deb name)

Comment: dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of collada-dom-dev:
 ros-indigo-collada-parser depends on collada-dom-dev.
 ros-indigo-collada-urdf depends on collada-dom-dev.

dpkg: error processing package collada-dom-dev (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 collada-dom-dev

Comment: thx, saved my day

Answer (score 5):

The easy way to open **synaptic**. It will states you that a broken packages are found so you have to locate the broken packages and just remove then you can do whatever you like.

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me (although I'm on x86):

```
$ sudo vim /var/lib/apt/lists/apt.typesafe.com_dists_unicorn_main_binary-i386_Packages
```

Change the line reading

```
Filename: pool/main/s/scala/scala_     2.9.2-400_all.deb
```

to:

```
Filename: pool/main/s/scala/scala_%20%20%20%20%202.9.2-400_all.deb
```

Followed by:

```
sudo apt-get remove scala-library
sudo apt-get remove scala
sudo apt-get install scala
```

Comment: Nano is easier for some users. Perhaps you can document that one can also use `sudo nano` or `gksudo gedit`?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I couldn't update the system because of the following error when trying `sudo apt-get install -f`:

```
update-alternatives: error: /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/package_name broken: invalid status
```

A remedy was to remove the file from `/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives` and repeat the above command. I ran it a few times until all the invalid packages were fixed.

In my case it prevented me from configuring Java properly.