# How do I install Ubuntu 12.10 from 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, 12.10

I tried using update manager but midway I had to stop it and log out and now everything is messed up. I typed,

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

To get the upgrade to complete and it failed whenever I open Update Manager I get the following error:
Not all updates can be installed

and then it goes on to talk about partial upgrades and says that, "This can be caused by: A previous upgrade which didn't complete"

Some other problems include no unity panel even when I start the app, when I log out and log back in the only desktop environments were: one Cairo-Dock, (GNOME) GNOME (without effects) GNOME

Please help me I am desperate the only solution I can think of is removing Ubuntu and installing 12.10 from scratch.

Comment: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/10/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-12-04-to-ubuntu-12-10

Comment: Already seen that doesn't really help me here though since it's all stuffed up.

Comment: I've the same problem, update manager crashed down and computer got turned down immediately while upgrading.

Comment: I've just solved mine ! Try this : http://askubuntu.com/questions/141370/how-to-fix-a-broken-package-when-apt-get-install-f-does-not-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can get into your system

1. BACK UP any data
2. Let the partial upgrade complete if possible
3. Once this is done then run update manager again

It is very important not to start an upgrade unless you can complete it in your current session.

Comment: It gives me this error when I did this: "Cannot upgrade: An upgrade from 'quantal' to 'precise' is not supported with this tool"

Comment: Open a terminal and try `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` - no guarantees with this and I would complete step 1 above before doing it (if you haven't already). If it reports errors post back but it is likely you may be better off re-installing after backing up your data.

Comment: Thanks mate, I won't accept your answer yet though just incase someone miraculously comes up with a better solution but I'll give you as many points as I can without accepting it.